# Intelligent chmod -x for all executable files that actually cannot be executed

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, chmod

Shot in the sky: do you have a script that does chmod -x on all executable files in the system that actually cannot be executed (i.e., they mistakenly have `x` flag)?

(context:
After copying backup files from NTFS into ext4, the files became executable (html, md, txt, etc.). 
I'd like to make the files non-executable, but only those that are really non-executable.
I will likely have to write the script that iterates over all files in the system (smth like ``` for f in ``find /path``; do intelligent_chmod -x $f; done; ```, where `intelligent_chmod` has to look into file and identify if it is either ELF or has the first line `!#...`, etc.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This uses uses `find` to look for regular files that have the executable bit set.  It then tests them with the `file` command to see if they really are executables or not.  If not, we run `chmod a-x` on them:

```
find . -type f -executable \( -exec sh -c 'file -b "$1" | grep -q executable' Test {} \; -o -exec chmod a-x {} \; \)
```

As you can see, this `find` command has two `-exec` expressions which are connected with a logical-OR operator.

#### How it works

- `-type f -executable`

  This tells find to look only for regular files that have the executable bit set.
- `\(`

  This begins a group.

  By default, `find` conditions are AND-ed together and AND binds tighter than OR.   In this case, we want to bind just the following two `-exec` commands together with an OR.  To do that, we need a group.
- `-exec sh -c 'file -b "$1" | grep -q executable' Test {} \;`

  This has the `file` program examine each file and `grep` checks to see if the string `executable` was in the output of `file` command.

  In the above, `Test` serves as the program name (`$0`) for the `sh -c` script.  (For a discussion of `$0` and `sh -c`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866883/how-to-use-positional-parameters-with-bash-c-command/).)

  Here is some sample output from the `file` command:

  ```
  $ file -b bash
  ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0e188133c8cc5187e22eabd27cbcf46f32060fe3, stripped        
  $ file -b which
  POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
  ```

  As you can see, `file` is smart enough to identify as executable not just ELF files but also a wide variety of script files.
- `-o`

  This is logical-OR.  This means that the command which follows will only be executed if `file` did not identify the file as an executable.
- `-exec chmod a-x {} \;`

  This removes the executable bit.
- `\)`

  This tells `find` that we have reached the end of the grouped commands.

#### Limitations

As described in `man magic`, the program `file` works by examining the strings in a file.  Many files have very distinctive strings.  An ELF executable, for example, begins with the hex characters `7f 45 4c 46`.  Jpeg and png graphics have similarly distinct markers.  `file` does not completely parse or analyze a file and, consequently, for some files, however, the magic fails.  As Ayrat points out in the comments, `file` misinterprets the following:

```
$ cat tmp.py
Now is the time for all good men
to come to the aid of the party.
from xxx import yyy
$ file tmp.py
tmp.py: Python script, ASCII text executable
```

Comment: your one liner just solved it! but could you clarify what does `_` mean in the command?

Comment: This will give false negatives in some cases e.g. for scripts that don't have shebang but this is the closest you can get..+1..

Comment: @heemayl: How would a script without a shebang be executed?

Comment: @WillihamTotland Run it as an argument to the interpreter, shell in this case.

Comment: @heemayl Sure. But for that +x is irrelevant.

Comment: @WillihamTotland Make a script executable, don't put any shebang, use `file` on it..

Comment: Confirm -- it gives false-positives for the following: try file tmp.py that contains (somewhere) `from xxx import yyy`. Running `file -b tmp.py` returns "ASCII text executable". The funny thing is that you _can_ actually run it (if flag is set to executable) -- and smth strange is run...

Comment: @WillihamTotland The default interpreter for files not containing a shebang line is `sh` [regardless of whether or not it actually contains valid shell commands... and since a command can be any word, `file` is just guessing based on whether it contains common ones]

Comment: @Random832 Ah. That just seems irresponsible.

Comment: @Random832 Not all interactive shells use `sh`, IIRC `bash` and `ksh` use themselves to interpret those files, don't use `sh`.. perhaps `zsh` uses `sh`.. I can't do the test right now though..

Comment: @Ayrat The `_` maps to `$0` which the shell treats as the script's name.  For a discussion on the use of  `_`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866883/how-to-use-positional-parameters-with-bash-c-command/)

Comment: @Ayrat Your `tmp.py` example is a good illustration of file's limitations: I just added it to the answer.